# Notion API How filtering using unique_id

Tags: search, filter, uniqueidentifier, notion-api

It is possible from now on to declare unique_id property in a Database.
But there is no information to how search an item from a unique_id

In the body of the API call, I've tried

```
{
  "filter": {
    "property": "Identifiant",
    "number": {
        "equals": 92
   }
 }
}
```

Not working
I got `[400] Could not find property with name or id: Identifiant` but `Identifiant` is the righ name of my property

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](https://developers.notion.com/reference/post-database-query-filter#id), you need to pass `"unique_id"` instead of `"number"`.

```json
    {
        "filter": {
            "property": "Identifiant",
            "unique_id": {
                "equals": 92
            }
        }
    }
```